# disk full issue in Hadoop yarn

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am using EMR & running a spark streaming job with yarn as resource manager and Hadoop 2.7.3-amzn-0, **facing disk full issue** so, I have implemented two properties **yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms as 600000** and **yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.target-size-mb as 1024** in yarn-site.xml then also my disk space is become full after some time and cross the limit which I configured. It seems my configured properties are not working and manually I have to clean the disk using this command: rm -rf filecache/ usercache/

every spark job is creating directory in filecache like:- /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/5631/__spark_libs__8149715201399895593.zip having all .jar files.

What to do for automatically clean the filecache & usercache? On which file and location do i have to change?

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I need some help with this as well...